# C# WPF MenuItem custom template

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate, menuitem

In Main.xaml I have these two menu items:

- The first with the header = **Disconnect from current**
- The second with the header = **Quit**
- ...
- More menu items with different header texts...

In order to edit some colors of the first item I created a custom template in App.xaml:

```
<!--Template for Menu Items-->
    <Style x:Key="MenuItemBaseStyle" TargetType="MenuItem">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#0a99f3" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <MenuItem Header="DISCONNECT FROM CURRENT" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

And in Main.xaml:

```
<MenuItem Header="CONNECTION">
    <MenuItem Style="{StaticResource MenuItemBaseStyle}" Header="DISCONNECT FROM CURRENT" />
    <MenuItem Header="QUIT"/>
</MenuItem>
```

Now I want to do the same for the second menu item. The problem is with the different header. If I delete the header from the template, it won't show any header even if the header text is still present in Main.xaml

How can I use this template for many menu items where the only thing that changes is the header text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use [TemplateBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189062(v=vs.95).aspx) on the [Header](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.headereditemscontrol.header(v=vs.110).aspx) property in the same way you've used it on the `Background` property:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
         <MenuItem Header="{TemplateBinding Header}" />
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: I have a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67767725/1232087) if you have any suggestions/comments etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can make an individual style for every MenuItem using a StyleSelector.

```
public class MyStyleSelector : StyleSelector
{
    public override Style SelectStyle(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var itemsControl = ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(container);
        var index = itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(container);

        if (index == 0)
            return (Style)itemsControl.FindResource("FirstItemStyle");
        if (index == 1)
            return (Style)itemsControl.FindResource("SecondItemStyle");

        return base.SelectStyle(item, container);
    }
}
```

And in your XAML

```
<Window x:Class="Menus.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Menus"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MyStyleSelector x:Key="MyStyleSelector" />

    <Style x:Key="FirstItemStyle"  TargetType="MenuItem">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#0a99f3" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="SecondItemStyle"  TargetType="MenuItem">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Menu ItemContainerStyleSelector="{StaticResource MyStyleSelector}">
        <MenuItem Header="Menu 1" />
        <MenuItem Header="Menu 2" />
        <MenuItem Header="Menu 3" />
    </Menu>
</Grid>
```

See StyleSelector here: [StyleSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.styleselector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Codebehind is so undesirable.

Comment: Where do you see a code behind?
MyStyleSelector is a separate class.